# is ～だ～だ another way of listing things, or does my JLPT book have a typo?

Tags: grammar

In my [JLPT practise book](http://www.amazon.co.jp/CD%E4%BB%98-TRY-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%83%BD%E5%8A%9B%E8%A9%A6%E9%A8%93-N1-%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E4%BC%B8%E3%81%B0%E3%81%99%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E/dp/4872178491), there is this sentence:

> 学生{がくせい}時代{じだい}は学費{がくひ}**だ**合宿{がっしゅく}だとお金{かね}がかかり、就職{しゅうしょく}したらしたで給料{きゅうりょう}だけで生活{せいかつ}できず、親{おや}に頼{たよ}ってしまい申{もう}し訳{わけ}ない。

I'm really just wondering about the part that says `学費{がくひ}だ`. That seems like a strange place for `だ`. I feel like it should be `や`, as in "(things like) school expenses and lodging". But is `～だ～だ` another way of listing things? I don't think I've encountered it before if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「Noun + だ + Noun + だと」 is a pretty common way to list 2-3 items.　The 「と」 at the end of the list is indispensable, too.

Nothing to do with the question but the 「就職したらして」 part makes little sense.  I would expect a 「就職したらしたで」 there.

Example:

> 「[夏]{なつ}になるとビールだアイスクリームだかき[氷]{ごおり}だと、つい[冷]{つめ}たいものを[摂]{と}りすぎてしまう。」
>
> = "In the summer, I tend to consume too much cold stuff like beer, icecream, shaved ice, etc."

This listing construction is often, but not always, preceded by the exclamation 「[やれ]{HL}」.
See #6 here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/223445/m0u/

Comment: Been in Tokyo a long, long time, but I swear, I really don't recall encountering the `Noun + だ + Noun + だと` form. Though, I've had this happen before where I've lived in blissful ignorance of some term or phrase for a long time, and then once I know it exists, it will then seem like I hear it all the time. `:)` Also, you're right, the example in the book is `就職したらしたで`. I had simply mistyped when copying from the book, so I'll correct the question.

Comment: 「noun だ noun だ」 is commonly seen in informal writings or novels. However it's not just a simple listing -- it implies that there are many other things of this kind, and that the speaker is somewhat overwhelmed or irritated about the situation. Maybe "AだBだ" can be translated into "A here, and B there, just to name a few".

Comment: @naruto:AFAIK, your comment is good complimentary answer in itself, by recording it as such it might get more (valuable) scrutiny from others.