# Meaning/translation of やれ

Tags: grammar, interjections

> 子供は**やれ肉**がすくないと文句を言っている.

What is exactly やれ? Is it kind of a とか or  やら？

Comment: Is that the whole sentence? Is it not in the form of 「やれXXX(だの)、YYY(だの)と文句を...」?

Comment: I didn't hear a だの but there was a word that I couldn't understand that is highly likely to be that

Comment: may be related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15084/9831

Answer (score 5):

やれ is a word that is used when you mention about two or more similar things. It has a nuance of complaining about the incident that is occurring.

Ex.

> 彼は僕のことを**やれ**ばかだの、**やれ**のろまだのと言い続けた。
>   = He kept calling me a fool and a dimwit.

Difference between とか and やら:

They are also used to list more than two things, but it doesn't necessarily have a complaining nuance.

Ex.

> けんそんな人は、家のまわりの[雑用]{ざつよう}**とか**家の[掃除]{そうじ}**とか**といったつまらなそうな仕事でも進んで行う。
>   = A humble man is ready to perform menial tasks such as doing chores around home or cleaning the house.
>
> バナナ**やら**リンゴ**やら**、果物をたくさん買った。
>   = I bought a lot of fruits - bananas, apples, and so on.

In the case of the question, やれ is used only once, but it suggests the kid's complaining attitude.

Answer (score 4):

This やれ is basically an old interjection similar to "O", "[Lo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lo#English)" or "Oh my". See [this dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8C/#jn-223445). As an standalone interjection, it's no longer used in modern conversations. (A similar interjection, やれやれ, is still common.)

However, it's still used in the form of `やれ A だ やれ B だ` or `やれ A だの やれ B だの` to list two (or more) things. This expresses A and B may be important to someone but the speaker has a negative (or at least indifferent) feeling about them. Both [AだBだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15082/5010) and [AだのBだの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25554/5010) already have a similar function, and やれ makes it sound stronger. This is a fixed pattern you have to memorize.

Your sentence is atypical in that it has only one やれ, but I feel there is still a list (of complaints). The use of やれ implies the child is trying to keep drawing attention by complaining, and the parent has a negative feeling about it.